# Gitolite access repair

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, gitolite

I have set up gitolite on my linux server and added my laptop to the gitolite-admin repository.  I was forced to format my laptop (bad hard drive) so I need to figure out a way to regain access to my other repositories gitolite controls.  It's worth mentioning, I have root access on my linux server, if that helps.  I am not very proficient with SSH/public keys, etc, so if someone can help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have version 2.0.3 or later installed, you can use the `gl-admin-push` command to push from a local clone of the admin repository:

See [gl-admin-push: bypassing gitolite for the gitolite-admin repo](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/adminpush.html) :

- `su` to your Gitolite user
- `cd /tmp && git clone ~/repositories/gitolite-admin.git`
- replace your old public key in `keydir/` with your new one, then commit
- `~/.gitolite/src/gl-admin-push` to push it; this will update the user’s `.ssh/authorized_keys` to integrate your new key

If you are using something earlier than 2.0.3, you can use the `gl-dont-panic` command to replace a key:

- `su` to your Gitolite user
- copy your new public key to `/tmp/username.pub`
  `username.pub` should be the same as a filename that is currently in your `keydir/`; you can list the contents of the existing `keydir/` with

  ```
  GIT_DIR="$HOME"/repositories/gitolite-admin.git git ls-tree master:keydir
  ```
- run `cd /tmp && ~/.gitolite/src/gl-dont-panic username.pub` to install the replacement key

Answer (score 5):

The answer above was helpful.
But for gitolite 3.04 (and probably later) use **gitolite push** instead of **gl-admin-push**.

Comment: Works perfectly! I was able to fix my broken account :) I exactly used: `~/gitolite/src/gitolite push`